# Calc 100% is applied to div, instead of h2

Tags: html, css, calc

I'm trying to create the yellow shadow under h2, like this:
[image]

However, what I get is this:

[image]

I see that the source code uses calc 100% to get the width of :after element.

```
ul li a h3:after {
width: calc(100% + 30px);
display: block;
content: '';
background: #fbf36d;
margin-top: -0.7rem;
margin-left: -10px;
height: 0.8rem;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
```

}

Below are my code snippet.

```css
.thing h2 {
  position: relative;
}

.thing h2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  background: #fbf36d;
  margin-top:-0.7rem;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="thing">
    <h2>Here is the title</h2>
    <p>I just don't get it, why the 100% width is applied to the div, instead of h2. Amazing.</p>
  </div>
```

Supposedly I missed out on something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the h2 as inline blocks.
the h2 is normally acting the same as a div - which meens that it is 100% wide.

If you make it inline-block, it will only take the width, that it needs.

```css
.thing h2 {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.thing h2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  background: #fbf36d;
  margin-top:-0.7rem;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
    <h2>Here is the title</h2>
    <p>I just don't get it, why the 100% width is applied to the div, instead of h2. Amazing.</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue I think you're referring to is that the h2 is currently displaying as 100% width of its container (the div). Try setting the h2 to `display: inline-block;`. This should solve your issue.